# Tkinter button default infinitely large

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to set up a basic GUI with two buttons and some number of labels (maybe 4 or so).

I was under the impression that Tkinter buttons had a default size that was relative to the amount of text contained in the button. When my buttons appear on the screen however, they seem to take up as much of the screen as possible depending on where I place them. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

screen_width2 = screen_width/1.3
screen_height2 = screen_height/1.3

a = str(int(screen_width2)) + "x" + str(int(screen_height2))

root.geometry (a)

root.title("Tester")

welcomeUser = Label(root, text ="Welcome User")
upload = Button(root, text="Upload")
run = Button(root, text="Run")

welcomeUser.place(bordermode=INSIDE, relheight= 0.25, relwidth= 1.0)
upload.place(bordermode=INSIDE, relheight= 1.0, relwidth= 0.25)
run.place(bordermode=INSIDE, relheight= 1.0, relwidth= 1.75)

root.mainloop()
```

For example, when I run this code, the text for the "run" button is in the correct place, but the actual button takes up the *entire* window. Whichever button is run last eclipses everything else in the window.

I tried to resize the button with `config()` and just by changing the size within its own parameters like `run = Button(root, text="Run", height=100, width=100)`.

I know it has something to do with the fact that I'm using `place()`, because when I use `pack()` or `grid()`, the button size is default (size of text).

For the people who are going to say "Use `grid` instead of `place()`" - I can't figure out how `grid()` would better. It seems much less intuitive and much less effective, especially for screen resolution dependent application window sizes (as is part of my code). In fact the whole format of `grid()` is much weaker than just using floats measures relative to window (I.E. how is done using place). I come from an OS background where this is standard practice, and people who use pixels etc are derided. The script seems to be flipped on StackOverflow with Tkinter, though. Feel free to change my  mind.

My question is, how can I can keep the buttons at their default size (encapsulating text) while still being able to place them effectively?

Comment: You're specifically setting the size when you use `place`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm not quite sure what you mean. The parameters I set are related to the actual placement of the widget, I thought. Are you saying that I am actually setting the size of the widget and it only appears to change the placement because of how large or small the button is becoming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use place and specify `relwith` and/or `relheight`, you are requesting that the buttons width or height be relative *to its parent*. In this case the parent is the root window.

Thus, if you set the `relheight` to `1`, you are requesting that the button be exactly as tall as the whole window. Similarly, when you set `relwidth` to .25, you are asking it to be 1/4 as wide as the whole window.

You can easily see this by simply removing the `relwidth` and `relheight` properties and the buttons will be their natural size.

Comment: It seems what I meant to use was relx and rely